# Steps to clean up terminal?

Tags: terminal

I installed on a new M1 mac using a time machine backup from a very old 2014 Mac I've been using for years, and also upgraded to Ventura. Additionally, I've used numerous VMs over the years (VMWare, etc).

Naturally, my terminal is having problems such as wrong path installations, certain programs use deprecated releases. Examples include `python` cmds using an older version installed instead of newer one; node installed but not nvm; $PATH was using something in VMWare. It's a giant mess...

Any way to easily clean things up? Or if a clean installation on a new user is the best option, then how to prepare to carry everything over except all the messed up dev stuff?

Comment: Which shell are you using (run `echo $0` if you don't know)?

Comment: I'm using -zsh as shell

Comment: So check .zprofile, .zshrc for any definitions which are outdated. If you miss any commands (like nvm) you may need to reinstall them (which probably makes sense anyway to get the ARM versions).

Comment: Thanks. I have a clean .zprofile and .zshrc file with default path. Brew doctor helps to get rid of things too. Will try to figure out more from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this [excellent guide](https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/index.html) that takes M1 & migration into account.

Their guide on [homebrew uninstall](https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/5.html) was very useful because homebrew used the old mac configurations which caused problems.

I got stuck because of (1) Ventura issues (can no longer duplicate terminal for Rosetta) and (2) various errors that prevented full installation of homebrew such as some HTTP flow connection, remote end hung up unexpectedly, unknown revision or path, etc. Something to do with GitHub disliking slow internet, VPNs, and certain geographic locations. An alternative to this might be using homebrew [mirrors](https://mirrors.sustech.edu.cn/help/homebrew.html) but I haven't tried this (if you try and want to [change back](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-change-brew-core-from-mirror-to-official/16033))

Using the sources at the bottom, I was able to do a functioning install of homebrew in this way:

```
cd /opt/
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew
eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
brew update --force --quiet
chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh"
cd /opt/homebrew/bin/
PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin
cd
touch .zshrc
echo export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin >> .zshrc
```

Sources:

- [Untar anywhere (unsupported)](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere-unsupported)
- [Fixing zsh command not found: brew? (installing Homebrew)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619529/fixing-zsh-command-not-found-brew-installing-homebrew)
- [Fixing zsh command not found: brew? (installing Homebrew)](https://medium.com/macoclock/a-clean-approach-to-installing-homebrew-d17c797fb045)
- [Install Homebrew and the Latest Git on your Mac](https://ucfcdl.github.io/techrangers-handbook/how-to/install-homebrew-git.html)

Other useful posts:

- [Unable to install: "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/666)
- [not able to install homebrew on m1 MacBook](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/668)

M1 MBP, Ventura OS